# How to solve the assert failure

Tags: qt

when i disconnect my server , the application throws an error saying

> ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to
>   objects owned by a different thread. Current thread be0cf8. Receiver
>   '' (of type 'QNativeSocketEngine') was created in thread cc39d4"

I am not under standing what is causing the problem

i have three threads running in my application ,

MainWindow.cpp:

```
    void MainWindow::on_pushbutton_clicked()
    {
    ui->pushbutton->setDisabled(true);


   thread1.m_TargetIpAddress.setAddress(IP Address);
   thread1.m_iTargetPort  = ui->TargetPortNumber->text().toInt();

    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    }
```

1st thread :

some of the socket operations like send , receive , connecttotarget , disconnectfrom host are done here

2nd thread :

i will connect to server from second thread.

3rd thread :

In this i will continuously send some command and receive some data from server.
I am using while(var) , when ever connection is established this var value will be updated to one and when ever server disconnects var value is updated as 0(zero) . thread 3 will be started once connection is established with server .

These are my sequence . Now my problem is when the server disconnects , I dont get the disconnected signal emitted from my application .

this is my signal and slot

connect(&obj, &QTcpSocket::disconnected,this,&MainWindow::TargetConnectionStatus,Qt::UniqueConnection);

```
 TargetConnectionStatus()
  {
      var = 0;
   }
```

as this slots is not being emitted the thread is continuously running and suddenly this assert failure occurs , How to solve this error .

Comment: Please add a language tag

Comment: I don't know how it works if you specify qt::UniqueConnection but across threads signals and slots should be connected with qt::QueuedConnection (or qt::AutoConnection). I suggest you try `qt::QueuedConnection | qt::UniqueConnection`.